# Chaining dependent API calls

Tags: ios, swift

I am trying to chain two API requests. One is for generating a new token and the other one is for fetching a list of elements (that one requires a valid token).

Call of these methods looks like this:

```
    AuthService.shared().authenticate() { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
               case .failure (let error):
                    // error processing
                    self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error generating token", comment: "Signup"))
               case .success (let result):
                    self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Token collected \(result)", comment: "Signup"))
            }
        }
    }

    ListService.shared().listAll() { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
               case .failure (let error):
                    // error processing
                    self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error fetching list", comment: "List"))
               case .success (let result):
                    self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("List fetched \(result)", comment: "List"))
            }
        }
    }
```

What I would like to do is to try to call `ListService.shared().listAll()` and if that fails with error, I would like to call `AuthService.shared().authenticate()` and then call again `ListService.shared().listAll()`.

What do you think it is the good way to go for?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. The messy way - simply nest all 3 calls together in the order you stated:

   ```
   ListService.shared().listAll() { result in
       switch result {
       case .failure (let error):
           // error processing
           DispatchQueue.main.async {
               self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error fetching list", comment: "List"))
           }

           AuthService.shared().authenticate() { result in
               switch result {
               case .failure (let error):
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       // error processing
                       self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error generating token", comment: "Signup"))
                   }
               case .success (let result):
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Token collected \(result)", comment: "Signup"))
                   }

                   ListService.shared().listAll() { result in
                       DispatchQueue.main.async {
                           switch result {
                           case .failure (let error):
                               // error processing
                               self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error fetching list", comment: "List"))
                           case .success (let result):
                               self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("List fetched \(result)", comment: "List"))
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
           }

       case .success (let result):
           self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("List fetched \(result)", comment: "List"))
       }
   }
   ```
2. Always try to authenticate first - this may result in unnecessary authentication calls, but will save you from nesting your code so much and still be better than the worst case scenario of your `listAll(`) method failing the first time, causing a total of 3 API calls (`listAll()`, `authenticate()`, `listAll()` again)

   ```
   AuthService.shared().authenticate() { result in
       DispatchQueue.main.async {
           switch result {
           case .failure (let error):
               // error processing
               self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error generating token", comment: "Signup"))
           case .success (let result):
               self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Token collected \(result)", comment: "Signup"))

               ListService.shared().listAll() { result in
                   DispatchQueue.main.async {
                       switch result {
                       case .failure (let error):
                           // error processing
                           self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error fetching list", comment: "List"))
                       case .success (let result):
                           self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("List fetched \(result)", comment: "List"))
                       }
                   }
               }
           }
       }
   }
   ```
3. Update your `authenticate()` method to store the token locally, and check for the existence of it before hitting the API. Then update your `listAll()` method to always call `authenticate()` first. This assumes your token can be used for more than one API call, doesn’t expire between calls, etc:

```
    class AuthService {
        private var token: String?

        static func shared() -> AuthService {
            return AuthService()
        }

        func authenticate(completion: @escaping (Result<String, Error>) -> Void) {
            if let token = token { 
                completion(.success(token))
                return
            }

            // Make your API call here and store the token when it completes
        }
    }

    class ListService {
        static func shared() -> ListService {
            return ListService()
        }

        func listAll(completion: @escaping (Result<Any, Error>) -> Void) {
            AuthService.shared().authenticate() { authResult in
                switch authResult {
                    case .failure (let error):
                        completion(.failure(error))
                    case .success (let token): 
                    // Make your list API call here
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Now you can call your `listAll()` method as normal and it will always be authenticated:

```
    ListService.shared().listAll() { result in
        DispatchQueue.main.async {
            switch result {
            case .failure (let error):
                // error processing
                self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("Error fetching list", comment: "List"))
            case .success (let result):
                self.alertError(errorTitle: "", errorText: NSLocalizedString("List fetched \(result)", comment: "List"))
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You might find it worth looking into PromiseKit, if not now, then eventually (https://github.com/mxcl/PromiseKit). Then you can use it to do something like this:

```
/**
This is just a facer for the real list all.
It will do the list all request, doing the authentication if it needs too.
*/
func listAll() {

    firstly {
        // Do the real list all
    }.recover {
        // List all failed, so we will attempt to recover

        firstly {
            // Do the authenticate
        }.then {
            // Authenticate succeeded. Do the real list all
        }
    }.done {
        // List all succeeded
    }.catch {
        // List all failed, and we tried to recover,
        // but a part of that also failed
    }
}
```